# How do I gather objects related to this primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I have access to this model in my view. From here I can also access champion which is a lolChamp. Now lolChamp has this infoID which is its primary key. This field is a foreign key to a bunch of other tables that hold information I would want. But I can't seem to get a hold of the information. I've already tried in my html. I got the idea from the django tutorial for polls.

```
{% for spell champBuild.spellSet_set.all %}
    <h1> {{spell.spell_name}} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

^that does nothing

```
class champBuild(models.Model):
    champion = models.ForeignKey(lolChamp, default="-1")
    build_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, default=time.time())
    build_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    items = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0)
    items2 = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0, related_name='item2')
    items3 = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0, related_name='item3')
    items4 = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0, related_name='item4')
    items5 = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0, related_name='item5')
    items6 = models.ForeignKey(lolItem, default=0, related_name='item6')

class lolChamp(models.Model):
    champ_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    champ_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    full_img = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sprite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    w = models.IntegerField()
    h = models.IntegerField()
    tags = models.TextField()
    infoID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.champ_name
class spellSet(models.Model):
    champid = models.ForeignKey(lolChamp, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    spell_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    full_img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.spell_name
```

And this is in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import champBuild
from lolBuilds.models import lolItem, skinSet
from .forms import champBuildForm, champBuildUpdateForm
# Create your views here.

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = champBuild
    template_name = 'lolBuilds/detail.html'
```

How do I get my set of spells that all have foreign keys to lolChamp?

Comment: why don't you right a queryset? and why is a primary key explicitly defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
spells = spellSet.objects.filter(champid=champ.infoID) # champ is an object of lolchamp model
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Read about querysets